# Uploading a file using http post AND additional values

Tags: php, vb.net, apache

Here is my situation. I have created a web application in PHP which uploads files to my server through simple forms using post.  There is a very basic security where a user authenticates with username and password and gets an access token. They then select the file to upload and pass the token along with the file to upload it.  The server looks at the token and allows the transfer if the token is valid and hasn't expired.

An additional part of the application requires me to interface with a VB.net client application. I need it to interact in the same way. It needs to authenticate, get a token, and send the file with the token to the server.  I've gotten it to authenticate and get a token, but I cannot find a way of posting both the file and the token in the same transaction.  The only method I found so far was to post the file in a stream, but that would totally bypass any security.

Am I missing something?  Is there a better way to transfer files AND have even a basic level of security?

Comment: Why don't you put the token into a $_SESSION variable and have it persist for the user. Then, on each page, check for that variable in the $_SESSION array, rather than posting it. Persistence is a wonderful thing. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem, Authentications happens first and file upload happens second,

So you can do something like this.

1. Authenticate user and save the access token in the $_SESSION
2. While uploading the file, After the file is uploaded and verified, Attach the Security token using $_SESSION,
3. Now Pass them to the next page.

Hope this will answer your question.